# Performance - str_01 == str_02 vs (object)str_01 == (object)str_02

Tags: c#, string, performance, string-interning

Is there any performance optimization in below code samples where I compare two string?

First:

```
public static bool Compare_01()
{
    string str_01 = "a";
    string str_02 = "a";

    if (str_01 == str_02)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Two:

```
public static bool Compare_02()
{
    string str_01 = "a";
    string str_02 = "a";

    if ((object)str_01 == (object)str_02)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

**Both of them return `true`.**

There is only one different in their **il** code:

1st:

```
IL_0001:  ldstr       "a"
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // str_01
IL_0007:  ldstr       "a"
IL_000C:  stloc.1     // str_02
IL_000D:  ldloc.0     // str_01
IL_000E:  ldloc.1     // str_02
IL_000F:  call        System.String.op_Equality
```

2nd:

```
IL_0001:  ldstr       "a"
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // str_01
IL_0007:  ldstr       "a"
IL_000C:  stloc.1     // str_02
IL_000D:  ldloc.0     // str_01
IL_000E:  ldloc.1     // str_02
IL_000F:  ceq
```

I found something like this in [System.String](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.String):

```
public static bool Equals(String a, String b) {
    // Here
    if ((Object)a==(Object)b) {
        return true;
    }
    // ****

    if ((Object)a==null || (Object)b==null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (a.Length != b.Length)
        return false;

    return EqualsHelper(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your version "Two" does something different: it compares for *reference equality* (you can see this in the `ceq` in the IL you added in an edit). This will *often work in basic tests*, due to string interning - but it should not be relied upon. It is working by accident only.

Basically, just use:

```
return str_01 == str02;
```

This is the idiomatic way of expressing "compare these two strings for equality", and it will be inlined to a call to `string.Equals(string a, string b)` *anyway*.

Comment: so why both of them return `true`? their reference should be different.

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh I already said: "string interning". Note that all constant strings embedded in code (and loaded via `ldstr`) will *automatically* be interned. Here's the counter-example: http://pastie.org/9789644 . Note that the IL in your examples uses `ldstr`.

Answer (score 4):

Comparing references is faster, but strings can have the same value even if they are not the same instance. As the comparisons are doing different things, you can't use the reference comparison as an optimisation for string comparison.

If you compare two strings that have the same value but are not the same instance, you can see the difference:

```
string str_01 = "ab";
string str_02 = String.Concat("a", "b");

Console.WriteLine(str_01 == str_02);
Console.WriteLine((object)str_01 == (object)str_02);
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

The `String.Equals` method is using reference comparison to catch the case when you are comparing two strings that are actually the same instance. If the strings are separate instances, it goes on to compare the value of the strings.

Answer (score 3):

The method `Compare_01()` and `Compare_02()` are **not** doing the same thing. The first one is comparing the string values while later comparing the references. Although both of them would return true as the JIT and Runtime will create a string `a` and assign the same address to both variables.

> Each string literal does not necessarily result in a new string
>   instance. When two or more string literals that are equivalent
>   according to the string equality operator (Section 7.9.7) appear in
>   the same assembly, these string literals refer to the same string
>   instance.  For instance, the output produced by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
class Test 
{    static void Main() {
      object a = "hello";
      object b = "hello";
      System.Console.WriteLine(a == b);    
     } 
}
```

Why not simply return the expression result that is `bool` (true or false) if you want to compare the values.

```
public static bool CompareStr(String str1 , String str2)
{
      return str1 == str2;
}
```

Comment: I want to know performance optimization in those code that microsoft use in .netFrameWork. I know that code.

Comment: Both of them return `true`.

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh if you mean `Compare_02`: it returns true for an unreliable reason; I can supply you examples where `Compare_01` returns true and `Compare_02` returns false if you refuse to believe us: http://pastie.org/9789644

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh the reference of both would be same because JIT and Runtime will create a string a and assign the same address to both variables

Comment: @Adil technically, that's the JIT and runtime, not the compiler; the compiler just does `ldstr`